# Error dataScroller

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am creating xhtml page with datascroller in another datascroller . the error that in the second datascrolle always doesn't show any thing.

this in index.xhtml

```
    <p:dataScroller value="#{ideeBean.idees}" var="in" chunkSize="10" mode="inline" scrollHeight="500"
       >
        <f:facet name="header">
       Les Idées 
        </f:facet>

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%" columnClasses="logo,detail">
<!--             <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/car/#{car.brand}-big.gif" />  -->

            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.titre']}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{in.titre}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.description']}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{in.description}" style="font-weight: bold"/>

                    <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.theme']}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{in.theme}" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                     <h:outputText value="#{msg['idee.type']}" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{in.type}" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                      <!-- ***************************comments******************** -->
  <p:dataScroller value="#{avisBean.avisl}" var="a" chunkSize="10" mode="inline" scrollHeight="500">
        <f:facet name="header">
          commentaires
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:100%" columnClasses="logo,detail" >
<!--             <p:graphicImage name="demo/images/car/#{car.brand}-big.gif" />  -->
<!--           <f:facet name="loader"> -->
<!--             <p:commandButton type="button" value="More" icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-s"/> -->
<!--         </f:facet> -->
            <p:outputPanel>
                <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputText value="Commentaire:" />
                    <h:outputText value="ggg" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dataScroller>
       <!-- ***************************************** -->
                    <h:inputText id="comment" value="#{avisBean.avis.commentaire}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="commenter" icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{avisBean.addAvis(in)}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dataScroller>
```

and this is the result of the code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI6x7.png)

Comment: Are you sure you have items on your `#{avisBean.avisl}` list? and dont you mean to iterate over `#{in.avis}` instead?

Comment: yes i am sure and i think it is not the problem because the outputs are static   <h:outputText value="Commentaire:" />
                    <h:outputText value="ggg" style="font-weight: bold"/>

Comment: i am sorry . you're right i check it now thank you